# Disable history when using Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent

When I am using Intent.ACTION_VIEW to open a specified URL like this:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Can I disable the history list of the started browser?

Comment: This may clear history of activity launch records.. `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);`

Comment: This flag may clear activity stack, however I need to disable the browsing history of the browser.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to remove history record of browser app from your application code, rather you can do one thing.. make one BrwserActivity having a webview in it, and open you link in your own webview instead the browser app.